# Проблема с декоратором callback_query_handler (с кнопками)

Tags: python, telebot, бот, button, декоратор

Новичок, создаю бота с помощью telebot на python 3.11. Хочу чтобы удалялись сами кнопки и сообщение, содержащее эти кнопки, после нажатия на одну из кнопок при выборе языка, они действительно удаляются и выводится соответствующее уведомление "Language preference saved"; но другие кнопки также задействованы в моем боте уже при выдаче списка блюд и при нажатии на них теперь сообщение с этими кнопками (и сами кнопки) тоже удаляется и выводится то же уведомление, что и при выборе языка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы удалялось сообщение с кнопками только относящиеся к выбору языка, и только в этом случае выводилось уведомление; а при нажатии на кнопки с названиями блюд сообщение с кнопками уже не удалялось и уведомление не выводилось.
Код выбора языка:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def handle_language_selection(call):
    user_id = call.message.chat.id
    user_language = call.data
    
    if user_language == 'ru':
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Введите список ингредиентов, разделенных запятыми: ')
    elif user_language == 'en':
        bot.send_message(user_id, 'Please enter the list of ingredients separated by commas')

    set_user_language(user_id, user_language)
    
    bot.answer_callback_query(call.id, text="Language preference saved.")

    bot.delete_message(user_id, call.message.message_id)
```

Код с кнопками названий блюд:

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def get_recipes(message):
    ingredients_list = message.text.split(",")
    url = "https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/findByIngredients"

    params = {
        "ingredients": ",".join(ingredients_list),
        "number": "14",
        "apiKey": api_key
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    recipes = response.json()

    if "message" in recipes:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Error occurred {recipes['message']}")
        return

    recipe_titles = [recipe["title"] for recipe in recipes]
    recipe_ids = [recipe["id"] for recipe in recipes]

    if len(recipe_titles) > 0:

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)

        for title, recipe_id in zip(recipe_titles, recipe_ids):
            button = types.InlineKeyboardButton(title, callback_data=recipe_id)
            markup.add(button)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Please choose a dish:", reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Sorry, I couldn't find dishes with these ingredients. Try again after a while.")
```

Comment: При необходимости, могу скинуть код бота целиком.

Comment: У переменной `call` есть параметр `call.data` это то что вы передаёте в `callback_data` проверяйте что у `call` нужный `call.data` к примеру так: `@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data in ["ru", "en"])` у функции `handle_language_selection`

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, все заработало, свою ошибку понял!